# focus on ToReciepient field in email - iphone

Tags: iphone, email

Is it possible to by default focus the keyboard on To field while opening the In-app email?
If yes then how can we access the To field in email?

Any path towards the goal will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to make these fields become the first responder.

if you add the following method to your class...

```
//Returns true if the ToAddress field was found any of the sub views and made first responder
//passing in @"MFComposeSubjectView"     as the value for field makes the subject become first responder 
//passing in @"MFComposeTextContentView" as the value for field makes the body become first responder 
//passing in @"MFRecipientTextField"       as the value for field makes the to address field become first responder 
- (BOOL) setMFMailFieldAsFirstResponder:(UIView*)view mfMailField:(NSString*)field{
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {

        NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [subview class]];
        if ([className isEqualToString:field])
        {
            //Found the sub view we need to set as first responder
            [subview becomeFirstResponder];
            return YES;
        }

        if ([subview.subviews count] > 0) {
            if ([self setMFMailFieldAsFirstResponder:subview mfMailField:field]){
                //Field was found and made first responder in a subview
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    //field not found in this view.
    return NO;
}
```

Then, after you present the MFMailComposeViewController, pass the MFMailComposeViewController's view into the function along with the field you want to become first responder.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

/*Set up the mail composer*/

[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
[self setMFMailFieldAsFirstResponder:mailComposer.view mfMailField:@"MFRecipientTextField"];
[mailComposer release];
```

Edited..

Comment: Changing RecipientTextField to MFRecipientTextField made it work

Comment: Balakrishnan thanks for the code.. any help with SMS controller for hte same?

Comment: This technique no longer seems to work in iOS 6. They're now using child view controllers and changed the class names to better conceal the internals. While I'm able to print out the subview names, attempting  to make any of them first responder fails.

Answer (score 0):

In that following code may be useful for that Problem

```
NSDictionary* defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
NSLog(@"Defaults: %@", defaults);
```

As you can tell, the defaults returned above are contained within a dictionary object. The list of keyboards in the dictionary is stored as an NSArray object. To retrieve the array, simply request the object for the key “AppleKeyboards”

```
NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"];
NSLog(@"Keyboards: %@", array);
```